# Read list in session inside XHTMl for rendering menus

Tags: jsf-2

I'm querying database adding all result into arraylist and keeping arraylist in session .Now i want to check whether this arraylist has data and render the menus in xhtml page.

If i use  i'm able to check the values but the menus also repeates thrice if the records are there in .

```
<ui:repeat var="a" value="#{sessionScope['restrictpageload']}" >
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{a.featureId eq 15}" >
                <li><a href="/xxx/page3.xhtml?ft=yes">PageName</a></li>
            </ui:fragment>
            </ui:repeat>
```

Please can anyone help me how to check value with JSTL tag `<c:if>` or any other .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `empty` keyword in EL for that:

```
<c:if test="#{not empty restrictpageload}">
    EL variable restrictpageload is not empty.
</c:if>
```

Or, depending on the concrete functional requirement (taghandlers like JSTL have a different lifecycle than UI components):

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty restrictpageload}">
    EL variable restrictpageload is not empty.
</ui:fragment>
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly specify the scope. That's only mandatory if you have exactly the same variable name in a lower scope such as the request scope — if you actually have one, you'd better rename it.